# Multipath destructive and constructive fading and the law of conservation of energy

Tags: wireless, digital-communications

Multipath in a Rayleigh fading environment causes fading, this fading could be destructive or constructive at a certain point or location in the far field, how does that align with the law of conservation of energy?

So in case of signal disappearance at a certain location (destructive fading) , i.e. no energy, does the energy show up at a different location?

On the other hand if it is constructive where does the "extra energy" (if I may say so) come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it obeys conservation of energy. All areas of constructive interference have a corresponding area of destructive interference. The additional energy you see in constructive areas is taken from these.

Furthermore, RF fields also obey the second law of thermodynamics, so this process always keeps total entropy constant or increases it. Thus you cannot combine two incoherent sources in such a way that energy spread across many modes constructively combines into a single (lower entropy) mode.

In the case of RF fading this is hard to think about, but it's pretty clear if you imagine the limiting case of monochromatic light in an interferometer or a wave bouncing back and forth into a 50:50 coupler (essentially two path propagation). By adjusting the arms of the interferometer you can send all power into one port of a 50:50 splitter and none into the other. Thus you have perfect adding in one arm and perfect cancellation in the other. There's no way to get more power out of the beam splitter than you put in though, since actually you are just moving energy from one port to the other. The multipath propagation example is essentially just like stacking a whole lot of beam splitters and thus a lot of overlapping areas of additive and destructive interference. As in the single splitter case, each path moves energy from one place to another but they don't create or destroy it.